# Is Constant Meditation Hindering my Creativity?

Tags: meditation-recommendation

I recently became more consistent with focused breathing meditation. I feel that since I practice, I tend to fall into such breath-focused meditation while walking, on public transport, etc. Yet, this type of practice is both much less focused than formal sitting, *and* it seems to inhibit otherwise free thought which I used for creative purposes.

**Is there a drawback to constant focused-meditation?**

Clearly, some times are needed to contemplate situations. **How does one know how to balance focused-meditation and other types of attention?**

Comment: Hi Eggman! Why are you meditating? What's the purpose of meditation in Buddhism? What is the purpose of the Noble Eightfold Path? What is the purpose of meditation in the N8P? Making those questions clear to yourself can help you answer the original question. Kind regards!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the Buddhas way or creativity, of meditation, has only one aim: to stop creativity, e.g all kinds of concentrations for becomings sake. So nothing wrong for one with right view or vision toward liberation.

What ever comes into being is a matter of the act of concentration, now this can be used, by right concentration, to gain independence, as concentration depends always on food.

So the question might more a matter of fear of independence, right, i.e doubt in the Rightly-selfawakened and meditating without having gone for a refuge?

Well it's of cause that one fears if having no refuge as base.

*{note: not given for concentration, burning of food and feeds for the world, but to gain liberation by observing the Dhamma with proper attention}*

Answer (score 0):

According to Buddhist teaching, you become more creative when your mind is concentrated.

=========

"With his mind thus concentrated, purified, & bright, unblemished, free from defects, pliant, malleable, steady, & attained to imperturbability, he directs and inclines it to whatever he wishes.

https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/dn/dn.12.0.than.html

When a mendicant has developed and cultivated mindfulness of the body, they become capable of realizing anything that can be realized by insight to which they extend the mind, in each and every case.

https://suttacentral.net/mn119/en/sujato